# Alternative to DiD estimtion

Tags: fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

I am doing a policy evaluation and wanted to do so with a Difference-in-Differences regression. There is an assumption about common trend, where the treatment group and the control group would follow a common trend if there had been no treatment.

Between the control group and the treatment group there is common trend up until period 3. Here the treatment group increases more than the control group, which is what I want to see. However the policy I am investigating is implemented in period 5. Hence I would like for the treatment group to have increased here, but that is unfortunately not the case.

I am considering doing a Fixed Effects model instead and include a dummy for the policy which takes the value 1 if the sector is affected and we are in the year of the policy change.

Is this a possible method to use instead of DiD or should I consider something different.

Comment: I have edited the question. I hope it makes it more clear.

Comment: Shouldn't the "rise" in the treatment group preceding the actual implementation of treatment count as a lack of evidence of the treatment effectiveness? It is a secular trend. If you decode the secular effects with dummies, the secular trend will still be rolled-up in the "pre" period.

Comment: Could people anticipate the treatment coming and adjust behavior, like in Ashenfelter's dip? This obviously depends on the institutional details which are scant here.